# How to Grab Specific Text from Webpage using PHP?

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to grab a specific text from a website. However, the text is unique every time a different username is entered in a textbox.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Enter Your Username:<input name="ign" type ="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Once the username is entered above it goes to the following code.

Process.php:

```
<?php

    $ign = $_POST["ign"];
    $url = file_get_contents ('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' .$ign);
    echo $url;
?>
```

So depending on the username you get something like this below:

`{"id":"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5","name":"Notch"}`

I need a way to grab those numbers in the second quotation (069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5) and store it in a variable. Also the numbers are unique for every username entered in the $ign variable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: that's json. `$data = json_decode($url); var_dump($data)` to see what structure php makes of it. if that's ALL of what you get, then `$data['id']` should do the trick.

Comment: It is JSON, so JSON decode it and access $json->id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine

```
$ign = $_POST["ign"];
$url = json_decode(file_get_contents ('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' .$ign));

echo $url->id;
```

`json_decode()` converts the text to a readable format for php, and is then accessible via $url->id.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked fine however I am unable to use the variable $url for something else. For example: echo "Your ID is: " .$url;  I get this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in"

Comment: If you want to do that, do `echo "Your ID is: ".$url->id;` You have to add the `->id` otherwise it's just attempting to echo an invalid object.